How do I query spans by trace id in DataDog
In Trace Explorer in the Spans view how can I filter to specific trace id or show trace id column?
I tried following names but all come as empty column and do not work as filter:

trace_id
trace
@trace_id
@trace


You should be able to search by @trace_id, and in the result set, click Options and add @trace_id as a column, as shown below. If this is not what you mean, please add more information.


That's exactly what I did and it just showed empty columns but today somehow trace_id and span_id are populated.

And it's trace_id for me rather han @trace_id

Actually it works with and without @. So weird
